# Error while posting question on StackOverflow

Tags: support, comments, asking-questions

Every time I try to post the question on stack overflow, I get the following error
"An error occurred submitting the question" 
Below is the screenshot of the error.

[image: Error while posting on Stack Overflow]

[image: Error while posting on StackOverflow]

As mentioned in the comment, I am also getting the same error while trying to post in my comment. Below is the screen shot of the same.

[image: Error while commenting on my post]

Comment: Have you tried copying the contents of the markdown to file, closing you browser, checking your internet connection and try to ask the question again?

Comment: Yes.. Even I have tried with different Internet connection. Still getting the same issue.

Comment: Try visiting over HTTPS and posting. Odds are there's an overzealous proxy or antivirus or something that freaks out at the code you're trying to post.

Comment: @AdamLear It really helped... I have posted my question... here is the link of the question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799988/attempt-to-call-method-random-a-nil-value-in-lua ) Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am getting the same error while I am trying to comment on my post. This time I am not able to add HTTPS in the link...

Comment: @tourism why can't you add https? what happens when you visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799988/attempt-to-call-method-random-a-nil-value-in-lua?

Comment: Ohhh.. my bad.. It is working now.. previously I tried and it was not working. Bdw Thanks for the reply.. It solved my issue...